# itext sharp merge pdfs with acrofields - fields go missing when merging

Tags: c#, itext

I have tried this now and its not working. `form.GenerateAppearances = true;` I merge my 2 documents and then save it. Then I open it again to populate all the fields. It says all the Acrofields keys are gone but when I open it in Nitro pro its there. Why can't I see them in code? Do I have to add something before I save?

```
private static void CombineAndSavePdf1(string savePath, List<string> lstPdfFiles)
{
    using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputPdfStream);
        document.Open();
        PdfReader reader;
        int totalPageCnt;
        PdfStamper stamper;
        string[] fieldNames;
        foreach (string file in lstPdfFiles)
        {
            reader = new PdfReader(file);
            totalPageCnt = reader.NumberOfPages;
            for (int pageCnt = 0; pageCnt < totalPageCnt; )
            {
                //have to create new reader for each page or PdfStamper will throw error
                reader = new PdfReader(file);
                stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
                fieldNames = new string[stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Keys.Count];
                stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Keys.CopyTo(fieldNames, 0);
                foreach (string name in fieldNames)
                {
                    stamper.AcroFields.RenameField(name, name);
                }

                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++pageCnt));

            }
            copy.FreeReader(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are merging the documents the wrong way. See [`MergeForms`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms) to find out how to do it correctly. The key line that is missing in your code, is:

```
copy.setMergeFields();
```

Without it, the fields disappear (as you have noticed).

There's also a [`MergeForms2`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms2) example that explains how to merge two identical forms. In this case, you need to rename the fields, because each field needs to have a unique name. I'm adding a reference to this second example, because I see that you also try renaming the fields. There is, however, a serious flaw in your code: you create a `stamper` object, but you never do `stamper.close()`. Your use of the `reader` object is also problematic. All in all, it would be best to throw away your code, and to start anew using the two examples from the official iText web site.

**Update:** I've added the tags [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) and [itextsharp](/questions/tagged/itextsharp) to your question. Only then I noticed that you're using iTextSharp instead of iText. Porting the Java code to C# should be easy for a C# developer, but I've never written a C# program, so please use the JAVA examples as if you were using pseudo-code. The code in C# won't be that different.

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();
    List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(renameFields(src, ++i));
        readers.add(reader);
        copy.addDocument(reader);
    }
    document.close();
    for (PdfReader reader : readers) {
        reader.close();
    }
}

public byte[] renameFields(String src, int i) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<String>(form.getFields().keySet());
    for (String key : keys) {
        form.renameField(key, String.format("%s_%d", key, i));
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: OK, please accept the answer; that's custom when an answer helped.

Comment: Added stamper.FormFlattening = true; to make it work for me. Otherwise stamper filling same data in all pages.