# How do I merge 2 PDF’s and keep the resulting file editable?

Tags: c#, itext

We are using iText to populate data in a pre-existing (editable) PDF form.  After stamping that data into the form we then merge a 2nd PDF document (a flattened scanned PDF typically) with the form, and would like the resulting document to remain editable.  The stamp & merge process works fine if we flatten the resulting file.  We thought it would be as simple as removing the .FormFlattening = true, but in the resulting file the data now doesn’t get stamped in the form, and the resulting document is also not editable.

Do we need to add a form field to the 2nd document or somehow change it (programmatically) to an editable document before the merge?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePathOfPDF, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var a = new List<byte[]>();
    a.Add(ReadFully(workingStream));
    a.Add(ReadFully(fs));
    var test = PdfManager.MergePdfForms(a);
    var asdf = test.DuplicateStream();
    return asdf;
}

public static MemoryStream MergePdfForms(List<byte[]> files)
{
    if (files.Count > 1)
    {
        PdfReader pdfFile;
        Document doc;
        PdfWriter pCopy;
        MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();

        pdfFile = new PdfReader(files[0]);

        doc = new Document();
        pCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, msOutput);
        doc.Open();

        for (int k = 0; k < files.Count; k++)
        {
            pdfFile = new PdfReader(files[k]);


            for (int i = 1; i < pdfFile.NumberOfPages + 1; i++)
            {
                ((PdfSmartCopy)pCopy).AddPage(pCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfFile, i));
            }
            pCopy.FreeReader(pdfFile);
        }

        pdfFile.Close();
        pCopy.Close();
        doc.Close();

        return msOutput;
    }
    else if (files.Count == 1)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(files[0]);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: By *editable* you mean that you can *save* filled-in forms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [itext sharp merge pdfs with acrofields - fields go missing when merging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032931/itext-sharp-merge-pdfs-with-acrofields-fields-go-missing-when-merging) and you may also want to read some more about [generating appearances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282559/make-acrofieldsitextsharp-are-non-editable-and-set-bold)

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to answer. Yes, we’d like to be able for users to still edit the form fields. By editable I mean a non-flattened PDF that has been filled in with data we've provided such that you can change that pre-filled data.